# execute all the yaml file in one command line kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

i have lots of deployments yaml files and lots of services yaml files, i want to know if it is possible to execute all the yaml files at once ?
i tried this command:

```
kubectl create -f *.yaml
```

But it's not working

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inside any directory and you want to apply all the YAML

```
kubectl apply -f ./
```

or else you merge many `YAML` files in single `YAML` file

```
YAML1 content 
---
YAML 2 content
---
YAML 3 contnet
```

Answer (score 2):

Addition to @Harsh answer.

Apply resources from a directory:

```
kubectl apply -k dir/
```

Include the sub directories to include all manifest files from sub-directories.

```
  kubectl apply -R -f dir/
```

> -R, --recursive=false: Process the directory used in -f, --filename recursively. Useful when you want to manage related manifests
> organized within the same directo

Answer (score 1):

merge those by using

```
---
```

three dashes in one file